# Best open source ASP.NET MVC e-commerce projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

I need to get a e-commerce site up and running, but I really don't want to program it from the bottom up if I don't need to. I want to program it using ASP.NET MVC.

I'm looking for a good open source alternative (or one for purchase if it's modular enough) that I can use as a base and enhance with the needed functions?

It has to have all "normal" e-commerce functions, and also the possibility to integrate with a credit card API of my choice.

If anyone have any recommendations for me here, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: Also, there's ERPStore eCommerce FrontOffice It's French, but here's the English translated version of the codeplex repository:
http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?ref=Internal&from=fr&to=en&a=http://erpstore.codeplex.com/ It's created and used by www.erpstore.com.

Answer (score 11):

Right off the bat you can download and try out [The BeerHouse CMS and e-comm project](http://thebeerhouse.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex. This is an asp.net MVC based application with e-commerce areas setup and should be able to be wired up to most payment gateways. In addition, it's been around for a while, and has [two books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470410957) which walk through most of the code, design considerations, and it's solutions.

Good luck on your project, and hope this helps some.

Answer (score 6):

An other one you could give a go is [Suteki Shop](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/) which is done with NHibernate.

[Sutkei Shop on GitHub](https://github.com/mikehadlow/sutekishop)

> an eCommerce application. The orginal aim is to write a site for a fashion retail business. It includes a product catalogue, shopping cart and order processing...
>
> It's based on the following technologies:
>
> - .NET 4.0
> - ASP.NET MVC 3
> - MVC Contrib
> - NHibernate
> - Windsor IoC Container
>
> Built using TDD with the following tools:
>
> - NUnit
> - Rhino Mocks...
>
> [image: http://static.mikehadlow.com/Suteki_Shop_ProductPage.jpg]